# Spectrum of toroidal graphs

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory

We consider two graphs, the toroidal knight's move graph, given by $K(p,q)$, and the toroidal triangular grid, given by $T(p,q)$. These graphs are simply the [Knight's graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_graph) and triangular grid extended to a torus so edges can "wrap" around.

The vertices of $K(p,q)$ are elements of $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_q$, where $(v,w) \sim (s,t)$ if and only if either $(v-s \in \{\pm 1\}, w-t\in\{\pm2\})$ or $(v-s \in \{\pm 2\}, w-t\in\{\pm1\})$.

The vertices of $T(p,q)$ are elements of $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_q$, where $(v,w) \sim (s,t)$ if and only if either $(v=s, w-t\in\{\pm1\})$ or $(v-s \in \{\pm 1\}, w=t)$, or $(v-s = w-t\in\{\pm1\})$.

How might we go about computing the spectrum of $K(8,8)$ and $T(8,8)$, or more generally $K(p,q)$ and $T(p,q)$? My understanding would be to maybe convert the graphs to more known graphs by cartesian, direct, strong products, and determine the spectrum that way, but I don't quite see how to do so.

Comment: @JeanMarie my typos have been fixed. There isn't really a reference for the toroidal knight's move graph, outside of just an extension of the usual knight's move graph

Comment: Here is a graphical [reference](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37776/knights-on-a-torus)

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Either way, I have provided the definitions of these graphs which should be enough to solve the problem. Do you know how I may go about this?